# How to call a method of a Fragment from another Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, deprecated

How can I call a method of a Fragment from a DialogFragment, **knowing that TargetFragment is now deprecated**?

In the past, I could do it this way:

**ParentFragment**

```
DialogFragment dialog = new DialogFragment();
dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
dialog.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

**DialogFragment**

```
((ParentFragment) this.getTargetFragment()).myMethod();
```

This is no longer possible, because TargetFragment is now deprecated.

I read that I can use **setFragmentResultListener()** to pass variables, but how can I call the ParentFragment.myMethod() method from the DialogFragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found.

**ParentFragment**

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("result", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
        public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {
            String action = bundle.getString("action");
            if (action != null)
                if (action.equals("myMethod"))
                    ParentFragment.this.myMethod();
        }
    });
}
```

**DialogFragment**

```
Bundle result = new Bundle();
result.putString("action", "myMethod");
this.getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("result", result);
```

Comment: The new way looks unnecessarily complicated compared to the old way...

Comment: What if we want get back result from parent Fragment to DialogFramgent. Like DialogFragment want a value from fragment by calling its method to decide specific operation. how we can use this architecture in this case ??