# How to call a function of Fragment from Activity

Tags: java, android-fragments

A small example java game, i am trying to make it so that the menu has an option to restart a game. Currently i have a function within a Fragment that does restart a game if it is called. I am trying to connect a OnClickListener so that it calls that function, but cannot find a way to do this correctly.

```
//MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // ...
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.new_game:
                // THIS DOES NOT WORK, RESULTS IN NULL
                Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.GameFragment);
                if(f instanceof GameFragment){
                    ((GameFragment) f).newGame();
                }
                else if(f == null) System.out.println("null");
                else System.out.println("else");

                // THIS DOES NOT WORK EITHER, RESULTS IN NO LOOP
                List<Fragment> lf = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
                for(Fragment frag : lf ){
                    if(frag instanceof GameFragment){
                        ((GameFragment) frag).newGame();
                    }
                }
                
                
                //((GameFragment)findViewById(R.id.GameFragment)).newGame();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}

//GameFragment.java
public class GameFragment extends Fragment {
    // ... timers, and other stuff that works
    public void newGame(){
        // this works if you call it from within this fragment somehow
        obstacles.clear();
        running = true;
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
    }
}
```

I have found how to call a method [one Fragment from another Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66044490/how-to-call-a-method-of-a-fragment-from-another-fragment), but here i am looking to do this from the Activity. Am i somehow breaking the intended use of a fragment, because i didn't expect it to be this hard.